# Pause OpenLayers interaction until pan complete

Tags: openlayers-2

I have an OpenLayers map with thousands of vectors and a tiled strategy for retrieving them. I rarely get above 15fps panning the map, which is undesirable. I notice a similar Google Maps application consistently gets 40fps. Based on profiling, it seems the Google map does better because it pauses interaction, feature creation and destruction, and animation during the pan, whereas the OpenLayers map continues to process these events. Is there a simple way to tell OpenLayers to focus on shifting the features and nothing else during a pan?